# CruiseControl.Net switch from console to service

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have set up a cruisecontrol.net build server. When running it in console mode it works fine, but when trying to run it as a windows service it doesn't work. The log file shows the following message:

```
ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.CruiseControlException: 
Source control operation failed: No VSS database (srcsafe.ini) found.  
Use the SSDIR environment variable or run netsetup.
```

The ssdir is set in ccnet.config, so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if it's applicable but when I had problems switching between the Console version and the Service version it was down to access rights for the user I was starting the service as.

Perhaps the Service does not have access rights to the srcsafe.ini file and your account does(assuming that's what your using to run the console).

Apologies if I'm way off the mark, just trying to help!

Comment: Couldn't vote this as helpful cause of low reputation; sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issues when setting up our CI environment at work. If you can get log-in permissions for the service account you are using, you can log in as that account and run CC.NET via the console and debug your issues.